# SQL Server Threads and Degree Of Parallelism

Tags: sql-server, parallelism, maxdop, multi-thread

My understanding about SQL Server threads is that SQL Server breaks down an execution request within a session into several tasks and associates each task with a worker thread. So SQL Server always tries to use multiple threads (if available and needed ) to run a query, regardless of whether it is a parallel or nonparallel query.

But the following statement (*From book Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals (MS Press)*) seems to state something different:

**A parallel query execution plan can use more than one thread; a serial execution plan, used by a nonparallel query, uses only a single thread.**

Edit: My original understanding is (likely incorrect) a scheduler may (when there is a need) use multiple workers/threads from the same NUMA node to process different tasks of the same execution request when it is a serial execution.

For a parallel execution, multiple schedulers/processors would process the same execution request (which is broken down to several tasks) at the same time, and each of the scheduler will use (again, when there is a need) multiple workers/threads from their respective NUMA node.

In other words, parallel or not, there is a chance multiple threads are used.

Obviously there must be a flaw in my original understanding, but I don't know where the misconception is. Does my original understanding only apply when it is a **PARALLEL** query being executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My original understanding is (likely incorrect) a scheduler may (when there is a need) use multiple workers/threads from the same NUMA node to process different tasks of the same execution request when it is a serial execution.

A serial plan will not use multiple threads it will only use single thread to perform the task. When the *serial* query would start it would be bound to a scheduler and that scheduler will not perform any other task unless it completes this query. The scheduler may wait for a process to complete thus forcing query to wait.

It is also worthy noting that MAXDOP setting controls the amount of thread used for parallel processing and [MAXDOP is always specified per operator in the execution plan and not per execution plan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/01/05/why-do-i-see-more-threads-per-spid-in-sysprocesses-than-maxdop/)

I strongly suggest you read below article by Paul White

[Understanding and Using Parallelism in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-and-using-parallelism-in-sql-server/)